# Apply Spring AOP to beans from different application context

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-aop

Is it possible to apply Spring AOP to beans that were declared in an application context different from which AOP config is taking place? I have 2 application contexts:
*dataApplicationContext.xml* and *webApplicationContext.xml*. I would like to declare an aspect in *webApplicationContext.xml* to intercept method executions of beans that are defined in *dataApplicationContext.xml*

*dataApplicationContext.xml* is included in the main *applicationContext.xml* context file which is booted from `main(String args[])` entry point. *webApplicationContext.xml* is loaded separetly by `ContextLoaderListener` which is deployed in an embedded instance of Jetty.

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext( new String[] { "applicationContext.xml"} );
ctx.registerShutdownHook();

Server server = ctx.getBean(Server.class);

DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServlet();
          dispatcherServlet.setContextConfigLocation("classpath:webApplicationContext.xml");

ServletHolder servletHolder = new ServletHolder(dispatcherServlet);
ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler();
context.setContextPath("/");
context.addEventListener(new ContextLoaderListener());
context.setInitParameter("contextConfigLocation", 
      "classpath*:**/webApplicationContext.xml");
context.addServlet(servletHolder, "/*");
context.setSessionHandler(new SessionHandler());
```

Thanks.

Comment: I see the edit, and have a question, In your question, you mention the webappContext.xml is loaded using the ContextLoaderListener, but in the code, it is loaded from the Dispatcher Servlet. Also, it essentially states the same then, your webapplication context would be the dispatcher servlet's context and the applicationContext.xml would be the root context. right?

Comment: Yes, it's exactly the same scenario. For instance, I tried it, and when aspect is declared in webApplicationContext.xml, there are no method interceptions at all.

Answer (score 1):

If your spring application loads both context-files it should work out of the box. If not, you have 2 options:

- Make a parent context-file that includes both context-files.
- Include one context file from the other one. So in this case, I'm assuming that your webApplicationContext.xml will have an include of the dataApplicationContext.xml.

Answer (score 0):

You can definately do that provided your `dataApplicationContext.xml` is loaded using the  `org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener` 
and your 
`webApplicationContext.xml` is loaded using the `DispatcherServlet`

The reason being, by default the Spring container creates two contexts. 
the `root application context` and each Dispatched Servlet has its own `web application context`.

The spring documentation clearly mentions this

> As detailed in the section entitled Section 3.8, “The
>   ApplicationContext”, ApplicationContext instances in Spring can be
>   scoped. In the web MVC framework, each DispatcherServlet has its own
>   WebApplicationContext, which inherits all the beans already defined in
>   the root WebApplicationContext. These inherited beans defined can be
>   overridden in the servlet-specific scope, and new scope-specific beans
>   can be defined local to a given servlet instance.

And hence, the bean definitions that you would specify in your `root application context` can be accessed by your dispatcher servlet's `webapplication context`

In your case, provided the first line is true, you can access the AOP declaration from the `webApplicationContext.xml` since this is your web context and it can access the root context.